# EclipseLink/JPA EntityListener: Check if entity is modified

Tags: eclipselink, entitylisteners

I'm using default EntityListeners (preUpdate and prePersist) to write create and update timestamps to my entities. When a new child is added to a collection (OneToMany) and persist is called the parent record is send to the EntityListener and the timestamps are updated. My problem is that I don't want to update the parent if only a new child record was added to the collection. Is there a way to check if an entity was modified (inside the EntityListerner)?
Thanks
Andreas

Answer (score 0):

This might help you (not tested, but I think that it will work).
event is the `DescriptorEvent` you got, `object` is the entity you want to check for changes.

```
   UnitOfWorkImpl uow = (UnitOfWorkImpl) event.getSession();
   ClassDescriptor descriptor = uow.getDescriptor(object);

   boolean isNew = uow.isObjectNew(object);
        if (isNew || descriptor.getObjectChangePolicy().shouldCompareExistingObjectForChange(object, uow, descriptor)) {
            ObjectChangeSet changes = null;
            if (isNew) {
                changes = descriptor.getObjectChangePolicy().calculateChangesForNewObject(object, changeSet, uow, descriptor, true);
            } else {
                changes = descriptor.getObjectChangePolicy().calculateChangesForExistingObject(object, changeSet, uow, descriptor, true);
            }
   boolean hasChanges = changes.hasChanges();
```